# How to change bootstrap label background color after click using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap HTML page contents gender selection as brides and grooms . The when the page is loaded `btn-group` as follows

[image]

Then the mouse clicked (on brides button) and release mouse the `btn-group` as follows. The background color was changed and i tried to change in to red using `css`. but not working. Is there any possibility to change Bootstrap default label background color after clicking, using `css`?

[image]

CSS

```
.gender-label:active { background-color: red;}
```

HTML

```
<li>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-label">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
      <span>Bride</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-label">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
      <span>Groom</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: please check my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting default Bootstrap's styles, in this case you can create your own class and its necessary behavior:

```
<label class="btn btn-custom gender-label">

.btn-custom:hover,
.btn-custom.active,
.btn-custom.active:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/096e8ev5/)
You can check it!

Answer (score 4):

You can try using following css:

```
.btn-default.active{
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/somprabhsharma/pen/ZWvZxb

Explanation: Bootstrap adds a class named "btn-default.active" whenever you click on the button. So you need to override that class by using above css to change the background.

Comment: It the above solution solved your problem, please mark it as an answer. Thank You!